# Send call inside Poco C++ library not returning on Windows after running for some time

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, socket.io, poco-libraries

I have to connect with a [Socket.io](http://socket.io/) 0.9 server (for legacy compatibility reasons) from my C++ code. [socket.io-poco](https://github.com/himynameschris/socket.io-poco) looks like the only library that provides this functionality, so I have taken the plunge and pulled in [Poco](https://pocoproject.org/) in order to support that. Things mostly work, until they do not.

My process seems to stall on a [`send` call](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740149(v=vs.85).aspx). The call inside [SocketImpl.cpp](https://github.com/packetstash/poco/blob/develop/Net/src/SocketImpl.cpp#L301) does not return, but it takes around half an hour of disconnected execution to get to that state. I am not sure how to prevent and/or recover from the program getting into this bad state.

The program executes on Windows 2012 R2. It connects to the server and converses successfully, but the connection can become volatile. I will come back and the service will be not visible to the server sometimes. This can take hours or days to occur. My test scenario is artificially disconnecting the server and seeing what happens. That normally results in the program getting into this non-returning state in about half-an-hour.

Any ideas for how to mitigate or resolve this issue?

- A different C++ library capable of speaking Socket.io 0.9x
- Something I can do to the stale socket.io-poco code to make it more defensive
- Guesses as to what I or any of the layers in between have messed up?
- Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I decided I needed to learn more about Winsock, so I found [a guide](https://tangentsoft.net/wskfaq/newbie.html). That told me to look at setting `SO_SNDTIMEO` with `setsockopt`. After searching through SocketImpl.html I found [`setSendTimeout`](https://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Net.SocketImpl.html#24570) and found I can call it in the socket.io-poco call using [WebSocket](https://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Net.WebSocket.html).

I then just had to catch the exception and call a new `reconnect` function when the timeout occurred:

```
void SIOClientImpl::reconnect() {
    // Disconnect
    _heartbeatTimer->stop();
    _ws->close();
    // Connect
    if((handshake(_queryArgs)) && (openSocket())) {
            connectToEndpoint(_uri.getPath());
    } else {
        Poco::Thread::sleep(100);
    }
}
```

I don't know which to hope for: that this answer is helpful or that nobody else has to try and do this!